# Transfer google drive / calendar username from @gmail to a custom domain eg. @mysite.com

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace, google-calendar

Ive got a @gmail / @googlemail email account that i also use for google drive, google calendar etc..

I would like to update / transfer my google account username to a custom domain eg. sam@mysite.com instead of sam@gmail.com.

I would still like to keep my @gmail email address, but not use it as the username i use to login to google drive / calendar etc.

Is this possible ? If so how would i do it ?

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted, seems like a reasonable question, in the right stack exchange site, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Google might not support direct data migration/transfer between custom domain (yourname.com) and gmail.com. Of course one can use Google Takeout to download from one, but it might not be easy to upload/import back into second.

But, for your stated requirements, you don't need migration, as you are ok with two email accounts.You already have sam@gmail.com. What you essentially need to do is purchase mysite.com, add it to Google Apps (not free as of now), and then you are free to create any email there, so make sam@mysite.com

You will end up with two emails, both having gmail backends, @gmail will be standard, @mysite will be Google Apps. Later either you could auto forward (& send)emails from one to other, or delegate access, or use multiple logins in Chrome.

Delegate access might not work between different domains, but you can always connect one account in second, in gmail settings, and then can send and receive emails from both in one place.

Calenders can be shared between both accounts with variable access.

Google Drive - Google always keeps the originator account as owner of files/folders. The workaround I have found is share a folder between both with full access, and all child files/folders will carry parent folder's permissions.

Comment: "Google does not allow data migration in and out of custom domains (yourname.com)" that is not true

Comment: Does it now? I should have clarified, I mean from gmail.com to Google Apps, direct transfer. Obviously it has Google Takeout.

Comment: Please edit you answer to make it clear what do you mean.

Comment: The above, because the question is about Drive **and** Calendar and because data migration is a very broad concept.

Answer (score 2):

I have multiple accounts for various items, including domains.  You can just start using the new account and still keep the old one.  If you wish, share access to Calendar and folders until you are completely moved over.  I am logged into multiple accounts at one time in the same browser.  So basically, if you want to keep the accounts, there is no reason not to and no reason to feel you need to log into one only.

That said, if you really want to move things, there are a few options with varying degrees of success.

If your custom domain is a G Suite domain, [see the instructions here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1041297?hl=en) for transferring various types of data or [these for moving large amounts of data](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6251069?hl=en).  These may require you have admin access to the account.  There are a couple options in the Marketplace to transfer some items.

The Takeout utility is reportedly not very good for getting things back into the new account.

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't support changing a consumer level @gmail.com account into a G Suite (formerly Google Apps) enterprise level account. Having said that you can create a G Suite account for your custom domain then allow it [delegated access](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/138350?hl=en) to your consumer @gmail.com account.

You can also allow another account to [manage](https://support.google.com/a/answer/117596?hl=en) your @gmail.com Calendar.

There is no direct way to transfer data from a consumer @gmail.com account to a G Suite account provided by Google.

To allow the new G Suite account to access the Drive files you will need to share them from one account.

Comment: Delegate access only works for accounts on the same domain, otherwise you get an error message like the following one: `Error: You can only grant access to Google accounts in the domain 'gmail.com'.`

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to merge the accounts, but it will be possible to manage everything in the old account from the new one. By:

- Setting up email forwarding
- Setting your old account as as alias to the new account to send emails from the old account
- Putting everything in your drive in a folder and giving the new account editing access to the folder
- Share your calendar (with editing settings) to your new account

Basically, for every app you use, share as much as possible with your new account.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably not the answer you need, but it might still be useful for others.

If you previously had consumer-level google account associated with yourname@yourcompany.com (as you can have a google account without gmail), and the company has just bought G Suite, and your email address stays the same, then you can transfer all the data to your new G Suite account with a wizard. It will pop up automatically once you log in.

Comment: Not directly related with the question.